# Cannot open new tabs or windows in iTerm2 after upgrading to Bug Sur

Tags: terminal, iterm2, macos-bigsur

After upgrading to Big Sur (11.2), I can no longer open new tabs (Command+T) or windows (Command+N). iTerm2 flickers, but nothing happens. I also cannot split.

I can still duplicate an existing tab and switch to it.

I am still able to do this in Terminal.

Google, searching SU, and fiddling with settings have both been deadends so far.

Comment: works for me: iTerm Build 3.4.3, macOS: 11.2.1 (20D74). is it an option for you to remove it fully and re-install?

Comment: I tried re-installing with no luck. Upgrading BigSur to 12.2.1 now, and will report if that fixes things.

Comment: I use an app called appcleaner for uninstalling. have you checked that you don't have the folder `~/.iterm2` after removing iTerm2?

Comment: Looks like there was something wrong with my default profile that was causing the problem. Switching a new profile solved the issue.